# Please explain the following line of code for me. i.e pandas series creation using 2 columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
industry_usa = f500["industry"][f500["country"] == "USA"].value_counts().head(2)
```

This is a dataframe where some of its columns are `industry` and `country`. So why do we need to locate the 2 columns side by side while creating the `indsutry_usa` series. Please explain.

Comment: Check it out: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 1):

I will break it down for you:

`f500["industry"]`: This selects the series (column) with the same name.

`f500["country"] == "USA"`: This returns a boolean index containing `True` for all the rows which have their **country** column as USA.

`f500["industry"][f500["country"] == "USA"]`: As you might have guessed, this now is just like any other indexing we do in pandas. So, it selects all those "**industry**"s where the **country** is "USA".

`.value_counts()` : is just to do a count of the unique values. Like we have in `Counter` class in `python`

NOTE: The interesting fact is that you could change the order to - `f500[f500["country"] == "USA"]["industry"]` and still get the same result!!